# Is it possible to override file.delete() in android

Tags: java, android

I am doing a recyclebin app like dumpster. When i am going to delete any file from any file manager (Astro file manager, ES file explorer) , i am getting the file path of the deleted file using fileobserver. But fileobserver is returning after completion of the operation (operation like delete, modify etc..). Is it possible to get the file path before deleting the file ? or to override delete() ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override it.
You can do it like this:

```
File file = new File("path"){
                @Override
                public boolean delete() {
                    return super.delete();
                }
            };
```

or like this:

```
class MyFile extends File{

    public MyFile(File dir, String name) {
         super(dir, name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete() {
         return super.delete();
    }
```

}

Comment: I think you will have to implement all the methods of the interface that File.java implements.